# method doesn't close

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a problem. 
in my activity I have a button and when I click it I call a method. this method show me an alert dialog with a listview and i want save the item click to a variable and then i want to close the method but it doesn't close!!!
why??
I post the code of the method. 
My logcat doesn't give me any error.
Can anyone help me?? please

```
private void getValuta() {

    // AlertDialog creation
    AlertDialog.Builder miaAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    final ListView lV = new ListView(this);

    Cursor c = null;


    // Set the title of the dialogBox
    miaAlert.setTitle("Choose Valuta");

    // I call the Query 
    c = vdb.fetchValuteListView("0");

    // handle of the cursor
    startManagingCursor(c);

    // I create the SimpleCursorAdapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, // Context
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, // row/product layout
            c, // the cursor
            new String[] {
                    ValuteDb.ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_NAME_KEY},
                                                                        // the colums
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1});// views

    stopManagingCursor(c);

    // The listView is filled using the adapter created above
    lV.setAdapter(adapter);

    miaAlert.setView(lV);

    miaAlert.setCancelable(false);

    // list view listener
    lV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            String riga = String.valueOf(id);
            String confr = vdb.getRecord(riga,2);
            System.out.println("position= " + position + "/id= " + id+"/nome= "+confr);
            new_valuta = vdb.getRecord(riga,2);
            listdb.update("9", "Valuta", new_valuta, "2");
            c_list.requery();

            return;

        }
    });

    // I create the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = miaAlert.create();

    // I showw the AlertDialog
    alert.show();
```

Comment: You might want to translate your comments, strings, and methods into English to get better/more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void getValuta() {

    // Creo l'alert Dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder miaAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    final ListView lV = new ListView(this);

    Cursor c = null;


    // Setto il titolo del mio alert
    miaAlert.setTitle("Choose Valuta");

    // Chiamo la Query che in questo caso è un all
    c = vdb.fetchValuteListView("0");

    // Comincio a fare il management del cursore
    startManagingCursor(c);

    // Semplice cursor adapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, // Contesto
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, // il layout di ogni riga/prodotto
            c, // Il cursore
            new String[] {
                    ValuteDb.ValuteMetaData.VALUTE_NAME_KEY},// questi
                                                                        // colonne
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1});// in
                                                                    // queste
                                                                    // views

    stopManagingCursor(c);

    // Ora la list view si prende questo adapter appena creato sopra
    lV.setAdapter(adapter);

    miaAlert.setView(lV);

    miaAlert.setCancelable(false);

    // Listener della list view
    lV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {


            AlertDialog alert = miaAlert.create();
            alert.show();

            String riga = String.valueOf(id);
            String confr = vdb.getRecord(riga,2);
            System.out.println("position= " + position + "/id= " + id+"/nome= "+confr);
            new_valuta = vdb.getRecord(riga,2);
            listdb.update("9", "Valuta", new_valuta, "2");
            c_list.requery();

            alert.dismiss();

            return;

        }
    });
```